# Passing parameters to an anonymous method using an action in C#

Tags: c#

We are still having problems passing a parameter to an action. Here's what we have so far:

```
public ActionResult Create(string ds) {
            HandleException(new Action<string, ref System.Web.Mvc.ModelState>(ds,ModelState) => {
                InitializeServices(ds, "0000");
                vm.Account = new Account {
                        PartitionKey = "0000",
                        RowKey = "0000",
                        Created = DateTime.Now,
                        CreatedBy = User.Identity.Name
                };
            }); 
            return View("CreateEdit", vm);
        }

    private void HandleException(Action action) {
        try { 
            action(); 
        } 
        catch (ServiceException ex) { 
            ModelState.Merge(ex.Errors); 
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        { 
            Trace.Write(e); 
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Database access error: " + e.Message); 
        } 
    }
```

This gives 12 syntax errors and most are pointing to the line:

```
HandleException(new Action<string,
```

We have also have syntax errors saying that "ref" is not the correct syntax

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult Create(string ds) {
            HandleException(() => {
                InitializeServices(ds, "0000");
                vm.Account = new Account {
                        PartitionKey = "0000",
                        RowKey = "0000",
                        Created = DateTime.Now,
                        CreatedBy = User.Identity.Name
                };
            }); 
            return View("CreateEdit", vm);
        }

    private void HandleException(Action action) {
        try { 
            action(); 
        } 
        catch (ServiceException ex) { 
            ModelState.Merge(ex.Errors); 
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        { 
            Trace.Write(e); 
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Database access error: " + e.Message); 
        } 
}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what the line should look like. I'm not quite sure what you mean. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Generic types expect types as their parameters... So Action requires actual types for each argument. "ref Type" is not a type. Ref is just a keyword.

As Jakub suggests, you should remove "ref" altogether and mutate your `ModelState`

Answer (score 0):

The argument of `HandleException` is of type **[`Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx)**, but you call it with an object of type `Action<string, ref System.Web.Mvc.ModelState>`, which is a specialization of **[`Action<T1, T2>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549311.aspx)**. These two types must be the same, just choose one of them.